# iAd not working in iPhone in landscape

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, constraints, iad

I have an app that only runs on iPhone in landscape. I have implemented iAd to put a banner across the bottom of the screen. This worked great when compiled in Xcode 4 but now in Xcode 5 there is a problem. When a user tapped the ad in the old version, the full size ad would load in portrait. But now when a user taps an ad, it loads the ad but only the top half of the screen has the ad - the bottom remains blank. It work correctly in the simulator and on test devices using the "test" ads, but now that the app is live it is broken.

Everything works perfectly on iPad, which is not restricted to landscape only. I have double checked my code and everything is just as the documentation states. Apple has been less than helpful with this. Any thoughts?

[image]

Update: I found 2 more pieces to the puzzle. This only happens with iOS 8. When the user taps the banner ad, I get a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error with the following:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c948310 H:[UIView:0x7c947e80(219)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94edf0 H:[UILabel:0x7c94ecb0'Elapsed\n0:00'(62)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94f180 H:[UIView:0x7c94a430]-(0)-[UILabel:0x7c94ecb0'Elapsed\n0:00']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94f210 UIView:0x7c94a430.width == UIView:0x7c94a320.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94f270 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7c94a430]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7c9479e0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94f2d0 H:[UILabel:0x7c94ecb0'Elapsed\n0:00']-(-1)-[UIView:0x7c94a320]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94f390 H:[UIView:0x7c94a320]-(1)-[UIView:0x7c947e80]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c94f3f0 UIView:0x7c9479e0.centerX == UIView:0x7c947e80.centerX>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c9504b0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7c9479e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7c94f920 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c9504e0 H:[UIView:0x7c9479e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7c94f920 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c971e90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7c94f920(320)]>"

"Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint "
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c948310 H:[UIView:0x7c947e80(219)]>"
```

And, the status bar is now covered by my view, whereas in ios7 it is shown. I built the storyboard layout originally for ios7 so something has changed. I don't really care (actually prefer) not having the status bar appear, but I can't figure out how to debug those constraints.

Comment: What interface orientations do you support in your Info.plist and your view controllers?

Comment: Landscape left and landscape right for iPhone.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards—could there be something there affecting the rotation and sizing? Can you make a new project with a single blank view controller set up landscape as yours is and try to reproduce the issue? I have an portrait and landscape app that displays iAd portrait-only okay on iOS 8.0.

Comment: I am using storyboards. But making a new project won't help - everything works fine in the simulator and dev devices. Its the apple signed app that is broken.

Comment: Yes it will. With an otherwise empty code-signed-and-installed on-device-app that reproduces the bug you can prove it exists, how it occurs and file a report at https://bugreport.apple.com to get it fixed. Often I find that going through the steps to recreate a bug reveals errors that were my fault and solve the problem. I do not mean to be rude but with a sample project posted publicly I can see how it behaves on my devices or notice if there is something wrong in the code and be able to help more.

Comment: JoePasq, thanks for your input. As you can see I have found a problem with my constraints that may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Storyboards—could there be something there affecting the rotation and sizing? I recommend making a new project with a single blank view controller set up landscape as yours is and trying to reproduce the issue there.

Some things that could be affecting this are:

- Storyboard misconfiguration or a forgotten view/setting
- Autoresizing masks / [Auto Layout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- Info.plist rotation and [view controllers preferred rotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)
- iOS content container sizes

Often I find that going through the steps to recreate a bug reveals errors, lets me see differences between a working version and mine, and ultimately correct the problem.

---

I find it easiest to compare these against the ones in a Storyboard. For deciphering them like this [refer to the visual format language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html).

It looks like the constraint ensuring a specific view is *horizontally* 219 equal to its superview is being broken. Check your storyboard for any auto layout warnings or errors, I have found it immensely helpful in Xcode 6.

You have several constraints, if you can remove some while debugging that can make things much simpler. Lastly if your subviews all reference each other that may make satisfying the constraints more difficult, if that is the case referencing the superview may help prevent conflicts.

Here are some references for debugging:

- [StackOverflow: AutoLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=autolayout)
- [[Older] Issues With Achieving Auto Layout Zen](http://carpeaqua.com/2012/11/02/issues-with-achieving-auto-layout-zen/)
- [Auto Layout In iOS 8 - layoutDebuggingIdentifier](http://carpeaqua.com/2014/08/27/auto-layout-in-ios-8-layoutdebuggingidentifier/)